# MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am getting an error "Value does not fall within the expected range". The stacktrace is given below. Please help...

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual(UIElement element, UIElement visual)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot.ReleaseMouseCaptureAtGestureOrigin()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot.OnManipulationDelta(Object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are getting exception. Only by seeing a stack trace how i give you the solution.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on what your app is trying to do, and what leads to this exception?

Comment: April now.  Can you supply some code?

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are trying to access main thread object or UI thread object in a asynchronous function.because asynchronous function's thread has lower priority so you cant access the main thread object from here..